# Stop Start WebRTC media stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc, kurento

I have been working with the Kurento docs to build a one to one recorded call.  This is using the adapter.js library.  It is working well, however when the streams are appended to the video elements they are extremely stop start.

By this i mean they will play video as expected for a second or so, freeze for a second and then restart playing again.

I have noticed this before in other webRTC libraries, but not all.

Is there something that I may be doing that is causing this?  I believe that this is not due to my computer as it works using native code only (no library).  Is this a known issue?

Comment: That's very weird. Have you checked with one of the tutorials, to see if the behaviour is the same? If it's not the same, then it's something in your code.

Answer (score 0):

chrome currently has an issue where something like this happens if you do not call play() on the video element and don't have autoplay set.
If you code does not play in Firefox at all that might be it.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the issue, please?